# Win32 ListView: Make colored progress bar for full row

Tags: listview, winapi, colors, progress-bar, custom-draw

I want to make a colored progress bar for full row in ListView. I take the idea from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/646482/Custom-Controls-in-Win-API-Control-Customization):

[image: Custom Draw]

In above image, we have colored progress bar, but only fo single cell. What I want is make same think, but for full row.
Here is what I have done:

[image: Make progress bar]

Not as I expected :) I tried to draw at the `CDDS_ITEM | CDDS_POSTPAINT` case. The code:

```
static LRESULT
HandleCustomDraw(NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pcd)
{
    TCHAR buffer[16];
    LVITEM item;

    switch (pcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
        case CDDS_PREPAINT:
            /* Tell the control we are interested in per-item notifications.
            * (We need it just to tell the control we want per-subitem
            * notifications.) */
            return CDRF_DODEFAULT | CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;

        case (CDDS_ITEM | CDDS_PREPAINT) :
            /* Tell the control we are interested in per-subitem notifications. */
            return CDRF_DODEFAULT | CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTPAINT | CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
        case (CDDS_ITEM | CDDS_POSTPAINT) :
        {
            // Test: assume the progress value is 50%
            float percent = 0.5;
            RECT r = pcd->nmcd.rc;
            r.right = r.left + percent * (r.right - r.left);
            HBRUSH hProgressBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));
            FillRect(pcd->nmcd.hdc, &r, hProgressBrush);
            return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
        }
    }
}
```

The expect result, for example at row `Item 8`, with `percent = 0.5`, is a filled rectange from start of the row, to between the third column, and the rest of the row is other color.
How I can achieve that? I know I have to draw different color for selected/focused/inative row, but I'm ok with it.

**Edit:**
Above image (the second one) is what I get with above code.
Demo what I want:

[image]

Comment: [NM_CUSTOMDRAW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775528.aspx): *"**CDRF_DODEFAULT**: The control will draw itself. It will not send additional NM_CUSTOMDRAW notification codes for this paint cycle. **This flag cannot be used with any other flag**."*

Comment: @IInspectable While you're correct, the value of `CDRF_DODEFAULT` is `0` so I don't think that's actually the problem.

Comment: @Sakura I'm having trouble working out if the screenshot you've posted is what you're actually seeing, or if it's a mockup showing what you want to achieve. If the former, can you please provide the latter (and vice versa).

Comment: @JonathanPotter certainly, please see my edit.

Comment: You've asked for subitem notificaiton, but you're not processing it. I think you need to be doing your drawing on `CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM`. Also you're leaking `hProgressBrush`. And to prevent the header control being drawn over you need to check the window the notification message comes from is actually the listview.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Here is `CDDS_ITEM | CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_POSTPAINT` case: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6FZZM.png I think if I paint with CDDS_SUBITEM, I can only paint one column per time. Then I have to check the rectangle of the cell if the `percent` position is not inside that colum, I set back color for that cell, otherwise I will do custom paint for it. That is only posible way I can imagine for now. It seem that I can't paint for entire row each time?

Comment: `NMLVCUSTOMDRAW.iSubItem` is the subitem ID. What did you do for the screenshot in your question anyway? It looks correct there, unlike that other question...

Comment: @andlabs I have 3 screenshots in the question and one in a comment. Which one do you ask? The first is from other page. I have link to that page at the first line.

Comment: The second screenshot.

Comment: @andlabs not sure why you say it correct. What I expect is the showed at the third screenshot. The second one is result of handle the custom draw message of the ListView, use above code.

Answer (score 0):

In `WM_SIZE` handler of the window retrieve and save the list view's client `RECT` (for example in global variable) with `GetClientRect()`:

```
RECT list_view_rc;  // Global.
GetClientRect(list_view_hwnd, &list_view_rc);
```

`RECT r = pcd->nmcd.rc;` in your `HandleCustomDraw()` gives you the rectangle of currently drawn item inside list view's client area.
All you have to do now is to replace `r.left` and `r.right` with obtained values from list view's client rectangle:

```
r.left = list_view_rc.left;
r.right = list_view_rc.right;
```

This will give you a rectangle for the whole row to draw into.
You have to do this only on last item drawn if you're using `CDDS_POSTPAINT`. This is why you need another global variable `list_view_column_count` which contains the number of list view columns:

```
int list_view_column_count;   // Global.
list_view_column_count = Header_GetItemCount(ListView_GetHeader(list_view_hwnd));
```

With `CDDS_POSTPAINT` you have to draw the text inside the items by yourself because you destroyed it with rectangle, or try to mix the rectangle with text by changing foreground mix mode with [SetROP2()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd145088(v=vs.85).aspx).
This is roughly the code you need (without text drawing):

```
static LRESULT
HandleCustomDraw(NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pcd)
{
    TCHAR buffer[16];
    LVITEM item;
    // This static variable works only if you're always calling
    // HandleCustomDraw() only for one specific list view.
    static int current_item_count;

    switch (pcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
        case CDDS_PREPAINT:
            /* Tell the control we are interested in per-item notifications.
            * (We need it just to tell the control we want per-subitem
            * notifications.) */
            current_item_count=0;
            return CDRF_DODEFAULT | CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;

        case (CDDS_ITEM | CDDS_PREPAINT) :
            /* Tell the control we are interested in per-subitem notifications. */
            return CDRF_DODEFAULT | CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTPAINT | CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
        case (CDDS_ITEM | CDDS_POSTPAINT) :
        if (++current_item_count == list_view_column_count)
        {
            // Test: assume the progress value is 50%
            float percent = 0.5;
            RECT r = pcd->nmcd.rc;
            r.left=list_view_rc.left;
            r.right=list_view_rc.right;
            r.right = r.left + percent * (r.right - r.left);
            HBRUSH hProgressBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));
            FillRect(pcd->nmcd.hdc, &r, hProgressBrush);
            return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
        }
    }
}
```